# SQL Server SSIS and SSRS Features required

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to use ssis and ssrs which version of sql server 2008 r2 should I download?

Comment: get SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition version 10 with full installation includes SSRS and SSIS

Comment: is your answer resolved ?? please mark it answered so that i can be closed